# How can i get back asp.net code from azure web app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I had published my application on azure web app and by mistake deleted the repository. Now how can I get back my code from the Azure web app? I had to try kudu but it's given an understandable format. the app in asp.net core.

Comment: i dont think you can, app would be compiled on the web app to work, there wouldn't be code. only dlls

Comment: Tip: If you have a dll, then there are several decompilers that can use that dll to create a reasonable approximation of the original source code

Comment: I retrieve the deployed code from the Azure web app now I want to convert deployed code to source code now how should I do?

Answer (score 0):

For now if you want to download the web source code, you could go to the kudu site, Select Debug console -> CMD from there you can go inside site -> wwwroot and select download.

However note that this is the deployed code, and it won't be the source if you are using a compiled language such as C#. When you publish from visual studio or any CI tool the files gets published in compiled form.

The option is you can use github deployment to maintain repository which contains all source file.

Comment: Thanks for answering is it possible to convert the deployed code to source code?

Comment: @Mahesh kumar, you could use [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy) to decompile it. Also in the visual studio there is the ILSpy extension.https://i.stack.imgur.com/HC2fW.png

Comment: If with this decompiler, suppose you have to restruct the project. If this could help you, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: I got the code from the Azure web app. I used justdecompile and dotpeek tools for crating source code but it's not properly work

Comment: Yes, it only decompile the file to c# code and output to cs file, it couldn't keep your project structure. So you have to restruct you project to keep the new project could run.

Comment: I have recover approx 75% code also got proper code structure but the problem is that View file did not recover properly the o/p file is just like as class file